# Executing a python script using Flask

Tags: python, flask

I trying to executing a Python script through Flask.

I wrote below python code to execute another python script.

```
from flask import Flask
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    subprocess.call("/home/tech/Downloads/labelme-master/labelme/main.py 1", shell=True)
    #return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But unfortunately when I run above python code and check the 127.0.0.1:5000 It's giving this error in browser :

```
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

Any solution?

My ultimate goal is to open a python script via HTML page's Button.

Answer (score 0):

As a response, you have to return from the function. so you can do like this

```
from flask import Flask
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    subprocess.call("python /home/tech/Downloads/labelme-master/labelme/main.py 1", shell=True)
    return "ok"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: any idea how to run above python script using html Button?

Comment: You can make ajax call from javascript